# Comparison of binary vs tfidf Ngram features in sentiment analysis / classification tasks?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, n-gram, tf-idf

Simple question again: Is it better to use Ngrams (unigram/ bigrams etc) as simple binary features  or rather use their Tfidf scores in ML models such as Support Vectory Machines for performing NLP tasks such as sentiment analysis or text categorization/classification?

Comment: Unless you are using a known and used dataset then the only person who can answer this question is you.

Comment: Technically, tf-idf concerns the global collocations of your queries and ngram attends to the localize collocations of words in the queries you fire. When you prove whether one works better than the other, you can conclude whether global/local cues improves sentiment analysis significantly or not

Comment: In my experiments, on categorization of short chat sentences, I found out that using IDF slightly improves performance over binary features. The improvement becomes smaller as the training set becomes larger. But, as previously said, YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Steve mentioned in the comment, the best answer (and the ML-style way) is to try !

That being said, I'd start with binary features. The goal of your ML model like SVM is to determine the "weight" of these features, so if it is efficient, you don't have to try to set this weight in advance (with TFIDF or other).